# Implement cross-site posting rate limits to slow down spammers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, spam, rate-limiting

In the morning of March 19th, a newly-registered user [posted 11 spam questions in as many minutes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/conversation/coffee-diet-spam-train):

> [image: coffee diet spam train]

While [asking questions is rate-limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/262399), these rate limits are not applied across sites, allowing spammers to post on many sites in rapid progression.  These rate limits should be applied across sites.

Shog9 [agreed this is "low-hanging fruit"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4717102#4717102).

Comment: If at least 1 spam post is destroyed by either a moderator approving the flag, or by 6 people flagging, then the stackexchange spam filters will learn the spam, and block all posts that are exactly the same

Comment: related: [Let's re-evaluate the Question Timer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286036/lets-re-evaluate-the-question-timer)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did someone say bounty? Arrrr.

As Shog9 said, this is now implemented and deployed - there is no way to specifically override per site (will require re-engineering a bunch of bits and figuring out what exactly that would mean per site).

Comment: You can have it. I need your shipping address for the stroopwafels....

Comment: @404 - I don't follow. They could post elsewhere already. They will not suddenly be able to post on a site where they are rate-limited on due to bad questions there (different ban - different check).

Answer (score 27):

Oded implemented this earlier today. Right now, the [default rate-limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/165773) apply to new users on every site (where "new user" is defined in a way that requires some nominal participation *on that site*), forcing a waiting period between posting a question or answer after having previously posted one *anywhere else on the network*.

These are not particularly onerous rate limits, but should suffice to let the spam-handling mechanisms kick in before excessive quantities of messages can be generated.

At present, this overrides site-specific rate-limits, which is less than ideal. Hopefully Oded will take a crack at correcting this, and also chime in here when he does for a chance at that sweet bounty goodness.

Comment: Thanks for this first step, Oded has three days to earn that juicy bounty. Remind him it is not a ordinary bounty, it is a smelly one and comes with an additional stroopwafel.

Comment: I am not sufficiently familiar with rate limits, but a beneficial side effect of this may be that it prevents instant cross-posting.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - yep, that should certainly be a side effect.

Comment: do these limits really work? I just observed spammer dropping their stuff at 3 sites in about 10 minutes - Programmers, Workspace, Webapps - http://stackexchange.com/users/8306646/jeffreymosess

Comment: Default rate limit is something like 5 minutes, @gnat. Programmers and TWP were about 50 minutes apart, so plenty of time to squeeze another one in there on Webapps.

Comment: Shog, folks at MSO complain that their site-specific 90-min rate limit appears broken: [Aren't new users throttled asking questions anymore?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322157/839601) Could this be a side effect of introducing cross-site limits?

Comment: It very well could be, @gnat. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 6):

This is very unlikely that a new user have interesting questions for 3 different SE websites (moreover for 11 websites!). I suggest to apply a rate limit for more than 2 websites. This would keep flexibility by allowing an user to ask 2 questions on 2 different websites before applying a limit.