# Implement an asynchronous queue for new questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Today I have found out that the maximum allowed frequency of posting new questions is 1 question in 40 minutes across *all* Stack Exchange communities taken together.

Given that there are many questions on different topics on my mind, I could of course take notes and wait in 40 minutes intervals reading around or doing other things which sometimes leads to more new questions. Or I could try not to forget the questions and get anxious.

But, maybe it is possible to implement a queue feature, like I file a question, give it a processing priority "any time". This would relax me a lot as SE user.

p.s., Is there actually any level of achievement to overcome this limit somehow?

Answer (score 6):

According to [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/245360) the rate limit for new users asking questions:

> Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes, network-wide

This prevents users from spamming the site and posting a lot of low-quality questions. Allowing to put question in a queue not only defeats the purpose, it is also a lot of work for no gain at all.

The easy way out for you is to get more reputation on the network. 125 on a single site isn't too much to gain.

Comment: so does this limit gets lower or is from 125 no more there on sites where this is reached?

Comment: It is gone at 125 reputation.

Comment: per site independently from other sites?

Comment: that is good to know, thx!

Comment: @J.Doe: Correction: [125 rep on the site you are asking the current question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281953/does-the-new-user-rate-limit-apply-even-when-you-are-a-new-user-on-only-one-site). (The association bonus gets you within 24 rep of that.)