# Increase trusted user rep bonus on a new site to 125 from 100

Tags: feature-request, association-bonus

When a user trusted on other sites joins a new site, they get 100 free rep. This should be changed to 125, so that trusted users don't have to wait 40 minutes between posting questions.

Alternatively, base the 40 minute timer on <125 on that site AND < 3000 on all sites, so this doesn't affect user's that know how to use the site already. What am I supposed to do, stockpile my questions in notepad, and feed them in every 40 minutes?

Comment: Totally agree with Glorfindel below. We already have enough trouble stemming from the massive number of sometimes misguided HNQ upvotes. Plus, are you sure it's a good idea to ask so many questions in a rapid succession in a site where your only rep gain is from association bonus? I imagine cases of more than one legitimate, decent quality question from a 101-rep user in a quick succession are *pretty* rare.

Comment: 40 minutes is an extraordinarily short amount of time. My questions almost always take more than 40 minutes alone to write, then there's research time on top of that. I don't think I've ever seen a situation that would call for questions to be asked that frequently. I think that 40 minute limit could be raised to a couple hours, applied to everyone regardless of rep, and nothing would be effected except a few more short sighted questions would be filtered out.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Since the rate limit is applied based on posts on *all* sites, this is considerably more of a problem than you might think. Wanting to ask several questions within several hours *on different sites* isn't all that implausible or even necessarily short-sighted. In particular, meta posts in response to a bug or support problem after asking and questions across multiple sites asking about different aspects of a larger problem. If I ask a question on Space Exploration (where I have almost 4k rep) I don't want to have to wait 3 hours before asking here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let's re-evaluate the Question Timer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286036/lets-re-evaluate-the-question-timer)

Answer (score 20):

125 is also the reputation required for downvoting; it's a Bad Idea™ to give that privilege for free. Upvoting already causes enough problems (mainly due to the HNQ).

In between those 40 minutes, you're supposed to do research to increase the quality of your question, or even find the answer yourself. You can also use the Draft function to preview your question and save it; no need for a text editor.

If you look around, you'll hardly see any users asking multiple questions networkwide, even if they have the reputation for it. (If you want, I can write a SEDE query tomorrow for some statistics on this.)

Comment: The limit also applies to IP addresses, so if one's posting from a shared network, they can be blocked by other users as well.