# Disable the first question wizard for users that know other network sites

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I just posted my first question on softwareengineering.se and got the wizard like someone who never used a SE site before. 
I neither need to be told how to write a question before asking, nor do I need a popup that people can now answer my question or comment on it after posting the question.

Can the new user wizard be disabled, when the user is already active on other SE sites?

Maybe this could be coupled with the association bonus, but on the other hand you do not even need to have earned the association bonus to already know how SE works.

Comment: probably related: [Let's re-evaluate the Question Timer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286036/165773)

Comment: You mean the little pop-up modal? This thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQVWs.png If so, calling that a "wizard" is a bit of a stretch. :)

Answer (score 18):

Please don't.

You know how *some* SE sites work, which is good, but that doesn't mean you'll know exactly how the other sites work. There are site-specific policies which aren't always known, even by experienced SE users; the ask question wizard can be customised with those, per-site.

You'd be surprised how many SE users coming from non-recreational SE sites ask clear, detailed story-identification questions on Movies and TV. That still doesn't make them less off-topic. A clear warning in the "Draft your question" sidebar that those are off-topic would be useful for *any* new M&TV users.

Comment: If anything, we should be more in-your-face with site scopes for first questions. It would save a lot of flags and closures.

Comment: You could at least make it shorter and do not explain that people can answer, comment and vote on each new site that works the same as the others. Communicating the rules and FAQ is another thing. And modal dialogs with only an "OK" button are no good design in most cases anyway.

Comment: "You'd be surprised how many SE users coming from non-recreational SE sites ask clear, detailed story-identification questions on Movies and TV." In a more general sense, you'd be surprised at the number of users who have a high rep on one or more of the technical sites, who then go to non-technical sites and post absolute *garbage*.

Comment: I think @allo 's suggestion in the comment is worth considering: making it shorter and focussed only on the *site-specific* rules. Otherwise users will see *some* content they already know, think "Yeah, yeah, I know this already", and close without noticing the site-specific stuff

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 Modal dialogs are probably a bad choice anyway. People are dismissing a lot of modal or sticky dialogs on websites. Yes I accept cookies, no I do not want your newsletter, no I do not need push notifications, etc. without really reading them. When you for example require a specific question format, you could prefill the text field with the basic structure. But this issue may be worth an own meta post.

Comment: "A clear warning in the "Draft your question" sidebar that those are off-topic would be useful" This is not currently the case?

Comment: @Trilarion [no it isn't](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), but [I've proposed it](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4640/63559)