# You can't post in 40 minutes? I haven't posted anything in two days? Is it a problem?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, rules

I am trying to post on the *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site, but the message I get is that you can only post once every 40 minutes.

The problem is I haven't posted anywhere, anything in any community in the last two days. Why is it happening?

Comment: Are you using a computer/IP address that's also used by other users? From the [Rate-limiting faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/369802): 

`Users with < 125 rep on the current site, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network; similarly, if the same user posts a question from a different IP address, they may not be limited.)`

Comment: Well, I am using the library's internet, connecting and disconnecting might helped. captcha asked me questions and it is done. Thank you .... 

May be they thought I am robot.

Comment: this posting rate limit is [network wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278000/165773) - did you happen to post at some other site less than 40 minutes before that?

Comment: good_omen92, Network Engineer?, I noticed that you are not yet a member of our: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said you were using  the internet at the library. At that point, it's likely someone else already used this same library connection (with same IP address) to ask a question before you. From the [Rate-limiting faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/369802):

> Users with < 125 rep on the current site, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network; similarly, if the same user posts a question from a different IP address, they may not be limited.)

Comment: Though I am a network and wireless engineer, however, right now I am more interested in getting my work done than putting myself into technicalities, IP granularities, and further TCP's minutiae. It started working, Thank you. I am gonna accept your answer.

Comment: Can you tell me one thing, Why less than 3 people watch my question on math stack exchange, how can I increase views? As no one would answer if it goes this way?